# Descending offset fraction method

Tags: offset, fractions

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   float offsetFraction = ((float)(i+1))/(4);
}
```

gives 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1 respectively.

What I would like to get is in the order;
1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25

I could not figure out the required code to get it. Can somebody have an idea how to get these values respectively? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
for(int i = 3; i >= 0; i--)
{
   float offsetFraction = ((float)(i+1))/(4);
}
```

This starts with the value `3` for `i` and decrements it at each loop iteration.

Unless you are using `i` for something else, this is simpler to understand:

```
for(int i = 4; i >= 1; i--)
{
   float offsetFraction = ((float)i)/(4);
}
```

As you commented that you **are** using `i` for something else, perhaps you want the value `0` for `i` correspond to `0.75` for `offsetFraction`, `1` correspond to `0.5`, and so on:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   float offsetFraction = ((float)(4-i))/(4);
}
```

Comment: The problem is I am also using i for creating an array of sprites. My code is;    for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        float offsetFraction = ((float)(i+1))/(4);
        tools[i] = newSprite([NSString stringWithFormat:@"tool_%d", i], Swidth * 0.9, (offsetFraction * Sheight), self, 1, 1);

Comment: @user3108224 So does the value `0` for `i` need to match the value `0.75` for `offsetFraction`?